# OpenFileDialog to view pdf file c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just want to open a pdf file and not to use it. If the user wants to be able to print via a glider. I want to just pressing a button will open the file if Acrobat Reader to view

Comment: Do you want to know how to show an OpenFileDialog to ask the user for a filename, or do you want to know how to launch a filename in Adobe Reader?

Comment: "Print via a glider" is very hard to interpret, you'd normally fly them.  I'd guess at the Process class, possibly ProcessStartInfo.Verb = "print".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the PDF, try using the following code with the PDF's filename as the command.

```
string command=@"c:\Users\User\Desktop\hello.pdf";

var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(command)
            };

process.Start();
```

Comment: how to launch a filename in Adobe Reader?

Comment: This is the correct answer. The ProcessStartInfo method will open your file with whatever default program your machine is registered to use. So if you have Adobe as your default PDF viewer, it'll open the PDF file via Adobe. Make sure to check the file exists before running the process though.

Comment: @shlomi: If you run the code you will open the file with whatever software is the default. Are you asking how to specify the application you want to open it with?

Comment: The operating system will launch Adobe Reader automatically based on the file name extension of the command that you give it.  In this case, the command string ends with ".pdf", which the operating system will relate to Adobe Reader, assuming that it is installed in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Basic CODE:

```
  Dim FilePath As String = "<YourFilePath>" & "<YourFileName>" & ".pdf"
  Dim Process As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process
  Process.StartInfo.FileName = FilePath
  Process.Start()
```

Every time the relative pdf file will show on a separate window

Obviously you MUST HAVE Adobe Reader INSTALLED on the CLIENT PC

It works pefectly. Used in Visual Studio 2010.